# Group within a Group XSLT 1.0 with Sum & Count of Distinct Values

Tags: xml, text, xslt-1.0, grouping, distinct-values

I would like to implement a Group by function within Current-Group using XSLT 1.0...I have managed to get the top level grouping based on "Organization", but a sub group within using "Covers"; I have failed at :(

(http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpL/16) has the XML & XSLT setup currently used.

I also need to apply a Sum(Current-Group()/SumInsured) and a count of distinct(Addenda), but this is not supported with 1.0...Please help me experts.

Expected Output: (Text)

```
Client Sum Insured Report

UK
SNo.    Policy Number   Customer Name   Cover Note #    No. of Addendas Sum Insured Total Commission
 1       POL1           ABC             50242           2               40000       65
 2       POL2           XYZ             12345           1               30000       30
Totals :                                                                70000       95

US
SNo.    Policy Number   Customer Name   Cover Note #    No. of Addendas Sum Insured Total Commission
 1                      JKL             45678           0               10000       10
Totals :                                                                10000       10
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?Siebel-Property-Set EscapeNames="true"?><SiebelMessage MessageId="1-OC05" IntObjectName="Client Sum Insured Report IO" MessageType="Integration Object" IntObjectFormat="Siebel Hierarchical">
<ListOfClientSumInsuredReportIo>
    <GroupPolicies>
     <Addenda>50242-1</Addenda>
     <CommAmt>50</CommAmt>
     <Cover>50242</Cover>
     <Customer>ABC</Customer>
     <Policy>POL1</Policy>
     <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
     <Organization>UK</Organization>
    </GroupPolicies>
    <GroupPolicies>
     <Addenda>50242-2</Addenda>
     <CommAmt>5</CommAmt>
     <Cover>50242</Cover>
     <Customer>ABC</Customer>
     <Policy>POL1</Policy>
     <SumInsured>20000</SumInsured>
     <Organization>UK</Organization>
    </GroupPolicies>
    <GroupPolicies>
     <Addenda></Addenda>
     <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
     <Cover>50242</Cover>
     <Customer>ABC</Customer>
     <Policy>POL1</Policy>
     <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
     <Organization>UK</Organization>
    </GroupPolicies>
    <GroupPolicies>
     <Addenda>12345-1</Addenda>
     <CommAmt>20</CommAmt>
     <Cover>12345</Cover>
     <Customer>XYZ</Customer>
     <Policy>POL2</Policy>
     <SumInsured>20000</SumInsured>
     <Organization>UK</Organization>
    </GroupPolicies>
    <GroupPolicies>
     <Addenda></Addenda>
     <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
     <Cover>12345</Cover>
     <Customer>XYZ</Customer>
     <Policy>POL2</Policy>
     <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
     <Organization>UK</Organization>
    </GroupPolicies>
    <GroupPolicies>
     <Addenda></Addenda>
     <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
     <Cover>45678</Cover>
     <Customer>JKL</Customer>
     <Policy></Policy>
     <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
     <Organization>US</Organization>
    </GroupPolicies>
</ListOfClientSumInsuredReportIo>
```

XSLT Used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>      
      <xsl:template match="/SiebelMessage/ListOfClientSumInsuredReportIo">
  <xsl:text>&#09;&#09;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Client Sum Insured Report</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="GroupPolicies[not(preceding-sibling::GroupPolicies/Organization = Organization)]/Organization" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="GroupPolicies" >
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
        <!--xsl:value-of select="{$count}"/-->
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Policy"/>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Customer"/>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Cover"/>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Addenda"/> <!-- Getting Distinct Count of Addendas while it is not blank-->
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="SumInsured"/>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="CommAmt"/>   
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>            
  </xsl:template>        

  <xsl:template match="Organization" >
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>SNo.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Policy Number</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Customer Name</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Cover Note #</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>No. of Addendas</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Sum Insured</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Total Commission</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

     <xsl:variable name="temp" select="." />         
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//GroupPolicies[Organization = current()]" />

     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please post your xslt and xml here instead of just at a link (it is fine to do both if you want).  This way it doesn't disappear if that link does.

Comment: Posted as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change (line 47 on your link)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//GroupPolicies[Organization = current()]" />
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//GroupPolicies[Organization = current() and not(preceding-sibling::GroupPolicies/Cover=Cover)]" />
```

Change (line 21, 23, 25)

```
<xsl:value-of select="Addenda"/>
<xsl:value-of select="SumInsured"/>
<xsl:value-of select="CommAmt"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()/Organization and Cover=current()/Cover]/Addenda[string-length()&gt;0])"/>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()/Organization and Cover=current()/Cover]/SumInsured)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()/Organization and Cover=current()/Cover]/CommAmt)"/>
```

Change (line 13)

```
<!--xsl:value-of select="{$count}"/-->
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
```

You'll need to clean up the spacing/formatting a little bit more, but this produces exactly what your desired output calls for.

**Edited to add additional requirements asked about by the OP in comment**

To add the organization to the top of the tables, just add

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

to the top of the Organization template.

To add per table totals add the following lines

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(../../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()]/SumInsured)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(../../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()]/CommAmt)"/>
```

to the bottom of the organization template (after the apply-templates call), with the appropriate spacing and carriage return formatting.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I works perfectly. I dint think I would get a solution this fast. Just one more request, I would like to display the Organization before every table. Could to tell me where to place the syntax.

Comment: Also is it possible to have totals per table in the end? I have appended my output statement above to indicate the desired. Thanks a million.

Comment: As the first line of your organization template (add it as line 30 moving the carriage return line down one), just add `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.

Comment: Done Thank you. You've probably guessed that I know nothing about XSLT. Would it be possible to have the running totals please.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide those table wide totals.

Comment: WOW...Just out of curiosity, how long have you been working on XSLT. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. God Bless

Comment: About 6 years, but not professionally.  I use it for my own personal projects (although have used it to create grade reports for classes I've taught).  Unfortunately it does have a pretty steep learning curve, and grouping tasks is one of the most difficult things to do in XSLT1.  If it is something that you need to know more about, Doug Tidwell's book (simply titled "XSLT") is excellent and covers version 1 and 2.  That was my first introduction to it.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I was hoping you could help me with one thing...I need the output as is, but with XML hierarchy tags...Could this be possible?

Comment: I'm not real clear what you mean by "XML hierarchy tags".

Comment: Sorry about the late reply Matthew, I was trying to convince my TeamLead to use the text output, but I guess it wont happen. Please bare with me while I explain what is needed. My system will accept a Hierarchy and extract the value within a tag, i.e in my XML, "SiebelMessage.MessageId" produces "1-OC05". So I was wondering if it possible to put my Text O/P within similar tags to that the systems assumes it to be a hierarchy and reads the complete data and displays to end user. I know I am expecting rocket science out of XSLT, but I'm helpless. Pls any assistance from you will brighten my day.

Comment: I'm still not fully clear on your new requirements, but I think that I almost understand what you want.  It would be clearer with some example of the output you expect.  Even so, I think that should be considered a new question, so you probably should ask it as a new question.  Provide in the new question an example of the format you expect the output to match, and provide the XSLT you have so far (including the changes that this answer provided).  You may attract somebody else to answer it, but if you put a link to the new question in a comment here, I'll be sure to take a look at it.

Comment: Will do Matthew, Thanks for the reply

Comment: You can ignore the previous request, hopefully we will go ahead with the text file. I would like to add one more column please, the same I have raised as a new question at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854963/comma-separated-child-group-with-group-using-xslt-1-0). Its a comma separated list of data into one "Insured" column.