# Comma Separated Child Group with Group, using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having trouble adding a Comma separated group within my XSLT script. Column "Insured" is the targeted field which contains child tags that I would like to add as a comma delimited string into my report.

Expected O/P:

```
Client Sum Insured Report

UK
SNo.    Policy Number   Customer Name   Cover Note #    Insured           No. of Addendas Sum Insured Total Commission
 1       POL1           ABC             50242           INSA, INS2, INS1    2               40000       65
 2       POL2           XYZ             12345           INSB, INS3          1               30000       30
Totals :                                                                                   70000       95

US
SNo.    Policy Number   Customer Name   Cover Note #    Insured           No. of Addendas Sum Insured Total Commission
 1                      JKL             45678           INSC                0               10000       10
Totals :                                                                                  10000       10
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?Siebel-Property-Set EscapeNames="true"?><SiebelMessage MessageId="1-OC05" IntObjectName="Client Sum Insured Report IO" MessageType="Integration Object" IntObjectFormat="Siebel Hierarchical">
<ListOfGroupPolicies>
<GroupPolicies>
 <Addenda>50242-1</Addenda>
 <CommAmt>50</CommAmt>
 <Cover>50242</Cover>
 <Customer>ABC</Customer>
 <Policy>POL1</Policy>
 <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
 <InsuredAccnt>INSA</InsuredAccnt>
 <Organization>UK</Organization>
 <ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS1</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>5</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS2</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>25</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
 </ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
</GroupPolicies>
<GroupPolicies>
 <Addenda>50242-2</Addenda>
 <CommAmt>5</CommAmt>
 <Cover>50242</Cover>
 <Customer>ABC</Customer>
 <Policy>POL1</Policy>
 <SumInsured>20000</SumInsured>
 <InsuredAccnt>INSA</InsuredAccnt>
 <Organization>UK</Organization>
 <ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS1</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>5</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS2</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>25</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
 </ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
</GroupPolicies>
<GroupPolicies>
 <Addenda></Addenda>
 <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
 <Cover>50242</Cover>
 <Customer>ABC</Customer>
 <Policy>POL1</Policy>
 <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
 <InsuredAccnt>INSA</InsuredAccnt>
 <Organization>UK</Organization>
 <ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS1</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>5</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS2</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>25</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
 </ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
</GroupPolicies>
<GroupPolicies>
 <Addenda>12345-1</Addenda>
 <CommAmt>20</CommAmt>
 <Cover>12345</Cover>
 <Customer>XYZ</Customer>
 <Policy>POL2</Policy>
 <SumInsured>20000</SumInsured>
 <InsuredAccnt>INSB</InsuredAccnt>
 <Organization>UK</Organization>
 <ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS3</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>20</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
 </ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
</GroupPolicies>
<GroupPolicies>
 <Addenda></Addenda>
 <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
 <Cover>12345</Cover>
 <Customer>XYZ</Customer>
 <Policy>POL2</Policy>
 <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
 <InsuredAccnt>INSB</InsuredAccnt>
 <Organization>UK</Organization>
 <ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
  <GroupPolicies_Insured>
  <InsuredAccount>INS3</InsuredAccount>
  <InsuredShare>20</InsuredShare>
  </GroupPolicies_Insured>
 </ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured>
</GroupPolicies>
<GroupPolicies>
 <Addenda></Addenda>
 <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
 <Cover>45678</Cover>
 <Customer>JKL</Customer>
 <Policy></Policy>
 <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
 <InsuredAccnt>INSC</InsuredAccnt>
 <Organization>US</Organization>
 <ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured />
</GroupPolicies>
</ListOfGroupPolicies>
```

XSLT Used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>      
<xsl:template match="/SiebelMessage/ListOfGroupPolicies">
    <xsl:text>&#09;&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Client Sum Insured Report</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="GroupPolicies[not(preceding-sibling::GroupPolicies/Organization = Organization)]/Organization" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="GroupPolicies" >
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Policy"/>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Customer"/>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Cover"/>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="InsuredAccount"/> <!-- Comma Separated List of Insured Accounts per Cover-->
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()/Organization and Cover=current()/Cover]/Addenda[string-length()>0])"/>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()/Organization and Cover=current()/Cover]/SumInsured)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()/Organization and Cover=current()/Cover]/CommAmt)"/> 
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>            
</xsl:template>  
<xsl:template match="Organization">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>SNo.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Policy Number</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Customer Name</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Cover Note #</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Insured</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>No. of Addendas</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Sum Insured</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Total Commission</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="." />         
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//GroupPolicies[Organization = current() and not(preceding-sibling::GroupPolicies/Cover=Cover)]"/>
    <xsl:text>Totals:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;&#09;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="sum(../../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()]/SumInsured)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(../../GroupPolicies[Organization=current()]/CommAmt)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could someone please help me, if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <xsl:value-of select="InsuredAccnt"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured/GroupPolicies_Insured">
        <xsl:sort select="InsuredShare" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="InsuredAccount"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This is how you do sorting inside `<xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Thank u so much. God Bless

Answer (score 0):

First thing, instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="InsuredAccount"/>
```

you have to use the full relative path (starting from current `<GroupPolicies>` element):

```
<xsl:value-of select="ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured/GroupPolicies_Insured/InsuredAccount"/>
```

to access the `<InsuredAccount>` element. But then you will still get only the first occurrence in each `<GroupPolicies>` item. So in order to get **all** values and separate them with a comma, you should use

```
<xsl:for-each select="ListOfGroupPolicies_Insured/GroupPolicies_Insured/InsuredAccount">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The OP's code is actually not that bad for a beginner and there is no reason to be rude. It's safer to always put text inside `xsl:text`: `<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>`.

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude.

Comment: Thank you Kimmy, I guess it does not take a scientist to guess that I am a beginner!! Worse, XSLT is out of scope for my Job Profile and this is a one time task dumped on me. Even the existing code was written by a kind hearted StackOverflow member. I have to admit XSLT is kinda exciting especially when i see the beautifully formatted output. Thanks again.

Comment: @Matthias, thank you for the support, but I'm less than a beginner and the existing is not written by me :(...taken note of the "<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>"

Comment: Yes, there's a lot you can do with XSLT, and the best thing about this technology is that it's very "compatible", i.e. it runs on various platforms without any modifications necessary.

Comment: @Kimmy, I have one more request; would it be possible to display the Parent "InsuredAccnt" (INSA in my XML) as the first data in Insured Output Column and the child "InsuredAccounts" sorted on share. i.e INS2 having a share of 25 should come first followed by INS1 having the lesser share of 5? I have added the changes into the expected Output and XML. Please any help would be great.